# Io(language) startup error - .io_history

Tags: iolanguage, startup-error

I installed and was running the Io(language) command line interface fine in OSX but now I'm getting this error on startup:

```
Exception: while loading history file '/Users/andrew/.io_history', reason: No such file or directory
```

Any one have any idea how to fix it? I've made the file requested (but I don't know what to put in it.) Googling for this error hasn't helped (just gotta love Io's un-google-ability... :-) )

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on OSX. Just delete the .io_history file.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer seems completely non-obvious but it works!

Answer (score -1):

Try the following in a terminal:

```
touch ~/.io_history
```

Or just create a empty plain txt file and save it to ~/.io_history.

If you user name is not andrew, then i guess you just have to reinstall Io binaries.

Comment: the '.io_history' file is there... but nothing is in it. I am wondering if I should fill it with something?

Comment: No, you don't have to fill it with anything. the file just recorded commands you've typed in Io interpreter. But, provide the file is there, do you still get the same error message? Try to run Io with sudo maybe Io interpreter cannot access that folder.